# How to get content from Liferay through API?

Tags: api, liferay, liferay-6

The link is:
http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws?signature=/journalarticle/get-article-content-4-groupId-articleId-languageId-themeDisplay

I trying to use **JournalArticle** service and method **get-article-content** where are few parameters:

1. groupId (long)
2. articleId (java.lang.String)
3. languageId (java.lang.String)
4. themeDisplay (com.liferay.portal.theme.ThemeDisplay)

With *groupId*, *articleId*, *languageId* is clear. But I don't understand what to pass as themeDisplay ...

Comment: I tried as in [documentation](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/json-web-services) use -themeDisplay for sending null ... and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) req.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
```